# how do i open UEFI/BIOS through elementary OS?

Tags: microsoft-windows

I have come to the realization that linux is not good for gaming, and i'd like a double boot. How can I access the UEFI/BIOS to download windows then make a dual boot?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get into the systems bios, the simplest way is to reboot the computer then keep pressing the Esc button

If that does not work try this

```
Click the Start button and navigate to settings. 
Select Update & security.
Select Recovery from the left menu.
Click Restart Now under Advanced startup. The computer will reboot to a special menu.
Click Troubleshoot.
Click Advanced options.
Select UEFI Firmware Settings
Click Restart.
```

Your system will restart and take you to the BIOS.